# How can I determine what objects a call to ruby require added to the global namespace?

Tags: ruby

Suppose I have a file `example.rb` like so:

```
# example.rb
class Example
  def foo
    5
  end
end
```

that I load with `require` or `require_relative`. If I didn't know that `example.rb` defined `Example`, is there a list (other than `ObjectSpace`) that I could inspect to find any objects that had been defined? I've tried checking `global_variables` but that doesn't seem to work.

Thanks!

Comment: No, there isn't. You're going to have to use ObjectSpace. (Also, global variables and constants are not the same thing.)

Comment: If you're looking for another answer other than "No" - perhaps instead approach the question by framing why you don't want to use `ObjectSpace`

Comment: There's `Object.constants`, but that will only get you things defined at the root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although Ruby offers a lot of reflection methods, it doesn't really give you a top-level view that can identify what, if anything, has changed. It's only if you have a specific target you can dig deeper.

For example:

```
def tree(root, seen = { })
  seen[root] = true

  root.constants.map do |name|
    root.const_get(name)
  end.reject do |object|
    seen[object] or !object.is_a?(Module)
  end.map do |object|
    seen[object] = true
    puts object

    [ object.to_s, tree(object, seen) ]
  end.to_h
end

p tree(Object)
```

Now if anything changes in that tree structure you have new things. Writing a diff method for this is possible using `seen` as a trigger.

The problem is that evaluating Ruby code may not necessarily create all the classes that it *will* or *could* create. Ruby allows extensive modification to any and all classes, and it's common that at run-time it will create more, or replace and remove others. Only libraries that forcibly declare all of their modules and classes up front will work with this technique, and I'd argue that's a small portion of them.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you mean by "the global namespace". Ruby doesn't really have a "global" namespace (except for global variables). It has a sort-of "root" namespace, namely the `Object` class. (Although note that `Object` may have a superclass and mixes in `Kernel`, and stuff can be inherited from there.)

"Global" constants are just constants of `Object`. "Global functions" are just private instance methods of `Object`.

So, you can get reasonably close by examining `global_variables`, `Object.constants`, and `Object.instance_methods` before and after the call to `require`/`require_relative`.

Note, however, that, depending on your definition of "global namespace" (private) singleton methods of `main` might also count, so you check for those as well.

Of course, any of the methods the script added could, when called at a later time, themselves add *additional* things to the global scope. For example, the following script adds *nothing* to the scope, but *calling* the method will:

```
class String
  module MyNonGlobalModule
    def self.my_non_global_method
      Object.const_set(:MY_GLOBAL_CONSTANT, 'Haha, gotcha!')
    end
  end
end
```

Strictly speaking, however, you asked about adding "objects" to the global namespace, and neither constants nor methods nor variables are objects, soooooo … the answer is always "none"?